# RegEx: Find&Replace, when matching on something else

Tags: regex, replace, find

first of all, don't know if this can be done by regular expressions.

I Have a Json like this:

```
{"transfId":"S0722182156164591494745777M","messageId":"123","from":"5777","to":"59395436474","status":-1,"checkId":"1975","price":0,"keyword":"OK","errorCode":601,"errorMessage":"SUCCESS","date":"20150730 09:00:00","model":"wer_tr"}
```

in a file with 6000 lines, and have to change only the "checkId" value but only in those cases with certain value on others fields.
More clearly: Only want to change the "checkId" value when "keyword":"OK" and "from":"5777"

I Have found how to find it with: `\b5777\b.*?\bOK`
How to do the replace?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What tool are you using to run the expression on the JSON input? Also, I'd recommend spending a little more time and writing a script that uses a JSON parser so your regex can be simpler and much more reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression like this:

```
({(?:(?!}).)*"from": "5777".*?"checkId": ")[^"]*(".*?"keyword": "OK")
```

It only searches between an open curly brace, and the next closing one.  It has two capture groups on either side of the piece you want to replace.  You would replace it with a a string like:

```
$1<your_new_checkId_here>$2
```

https://regex101.com/r/fY8pA7/1

Answer (score 0):

You can get values with:

```
\{.+\"from\":\"(\d+)\".+\"checkId\":\"(\d+)\".+\"keyword\":\"([a-zA-Z]+)\".+\}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xA2uO1/1)

It is rather simple regex so should work in many languages.
Then using if statment, find if `checkId` should be changed, and change it.
You can also modify capturing groups and use substitution:

```
(\{.+\"from\":\"(\d+)\".+\"checkId\":\")(\d+)(\".+\"keyword\":\"([a-zA-Z]+)\".+\})
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cY1jF2/1)